# Equivalent socket. listen that there is in python , in java?

Tags: java, python, sockets

as you probably  know we have socket.listen(10) that limits the number of clients inside the server and server will responsible to answer to at most 10 clients.
i am searching something like this in java .
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't limit the number of clients. It limits the number of pending inbound connections that already exist and haven't been accepted yet. Once accepted, the number of client connections is only limited by available FDs, memory, threads, &c.

Answer (score 3):

That parameter in Python controls the size of the backlog queue. In Java it is set with the `backlog` parameter in the ServerSocket constructor. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int,%20int)

```
int backlog = 10;
var ss = new ServerSocket(port, backlog);
```